# How to add Custom fields in User model in django?

Tags: python, django

I am creating a website where I need extra information from the user when registering into the website , e.g.(he has a pc or not, subscribed to newsletter or not, email, phone number and password confirmation)
note:
is there a way that I can make in way that a react developer can use this model ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask] and [limit each post to one question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/39223/248627). Are you asking how to add custom fields for the Django model, or are you asking about React? What does a React developer care about how the fields might be stored?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a good example how to extend the `User` object in the django documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model

If there is the need to completly replace the `User` model, there is a django way to do this as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/auth/customizing/#substituting-a-custom-user-model

Comment: how can I use it outside admin page? like Django templates or html or react ?